Beginning of 2025, what are the most recent/best unit testing frameworks?
Starting next year, I will be assigned writing tests for some new applications, that will be developed by my department (now, I'm working here as a software developer).
I would like to prepare myself, and one of the first things to do, is to search for and get acquainted with the unit testing framework I will be using.
About the applications that will need to be tested:

The application will be client/server application, where TCP connections are used to pass messages from one to the other.
Both client and server application will be written in C#, the database technology is SQL-Server.
React might be involved, maybe XAML.
There will be communication to outer parties, mostly using TCP connections (TCP over IPv4, like the IP address/port "10.1.0.160:5000").
There will also be communication via Kepware (for contacting PLCs), in between there is a so-called OPC layer.
As both applications are to be developed in C#, I'd like a framework/library/..., which can be integrated in Visual Studio (2022).

I have background in testing (using SoapUI), generally my tests had the following structure:
- General setup
- General first testing
- Chapter 1: setup
- Chapter 1: testing
  - Subchapter 1.1 : setup
  - Subchapter 1.1 : testing
  - Subchapter 1.1 : remove setup (if necessary)
- Chapter 1: remove setup

Every test "chapter" contains a bunch of triplets of test cases, each of them looking as follows:
- Test Case x : setup
- Test Case x : testing
- Test Case x : remove setup (can be empty)

I would like to be able to launch individual tests, but also all tests of complete (sub)chapters.
It has been more than fifteen years that I haven't worked as a tester anymore, so I have lost track of the latest developments in that area. Can anybody point me in the direction of a good framework/library/...?
If you think "Jezus, man, such a general question. Can't you ask ChatGPT?". Well, I did: and one of the answers is gave was about MSTest, which, according to its tag, has not been used anymore since Visual Studio 2010: I prefer getting answers from people, currently working in the field.
